# Laravel upload image unable to read file if 1mb up

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, intervention

I am having problem uploading image, if I upload below 1mb it works find but if I upload 1.6mb image file, this will threw error.

```
  NotReadableException in Decoder.php line 46:
  Unable to read image from file
```

I also change php.ini
`post_max_size=3000M`
`upload_max_filesize=2000M` still no luck.

here is my code

```
        $filename = $request->profile->getClientOriginalName();
        $image = $request->profile->getRealPath();
        $path =public_path() . '/profile/';
        $fimage = Image::make($image)->resize(48, 48);
        $fimage->save($path . $filename);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: your values are overkill for the file size you are mentioning and don't expect to upload such big files without increasing memory limit and other limits. Have you restarted the web server after the php.ini change? Which web server are you using?

Comment: @bansi, at this moment I use apatche because I'm in localhost, but in my live server it is nginx...I restarted my webserver..what other limits should I change? ...this image is for user profile pic. do you have any suggestion for uploading profile pic to prevent uploading big file.?

Comment: for files less than approx 100M you don't need any other limit increment. The first limit you are going to hit after that is `memory_limit` which defaults to 128M (if you have not changed it in php.ini). Also try `post_max_size=100M` and `upload_max_filesize=100M`. Also check if your web server is using the correct php.ini

Comment: @bansi  100M is 1MB ?

Comment: no 100M = 100MB, M=MB, K=KB, and G=GB in php.ini

Comment: @bansi, what value should I change in memory_limit ?

Comment: @bansi is 100MB is not also over kill in server ?

Comment: Yes even 100MB is a overkill, keep it to minimum required. Regarding memory limit, you don't need to change anything unless your script is too memory hungry. You should read [Description of core php.ini directives](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit). But your problem looks like somewhere else, not those limits.

Comment: @bansi, Yeah I think so it's not in the limit is my problem.